# how to pass value from one page to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have three buttons on 1st view. now i have only one lable at 2nd view.

- By clicking on the First button i got value 1.
- By clicking on the second button i got value 2.
- By clicking on the Third button i got value 3.

now i want to print this value on the label which is at 2nd view when and every time i want only one value printed.

- when i press first button then remove label value and only 1 will print at label.
- when i press second button then remove label value and only 2 will print at label.
- when i press Third button then remove label value and only 3 will print at label.

### #

Comment: Do u have the label in another viewcontroller class ?

Answer (score 2):

Removing values is easy, because every time you call

```
[yourLabel setText:@"your value"];
```

you are deleting old value directly.

Now when we talk about moving info between views it's not that hard, you can use for example application delegate

Add in application delegate .h file

```
{
   // app delegate declarations
   NSString *buttonValue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *buttonValue;
```

And in app delegate .m file add

```
@synethize buttonValue //on the top
```

Now you add on your views

```
#import YourAppDelegate.h
```

And then in code

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And set value of buttonValue with

```
[appDelegate setButtonValue:@"value"];
```

Now when you are in the second view just read value with

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate buttonValue]
```

Comment: and beside label if i take a text then how will i take integer value in text

Comment: you can read value from string as integer value with [NSString intValue] so in your case you can have int in app delegate instead of NSString but then you need to remove retain from property in .h file

Answer (score 0):

Properties. Thats what you need.

In your seconde view, write property for your Label.
e.g:
in your .h file

```
@interface classname
{
   UILabel *myLabel;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)  IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

then in your .m

```
@implementation classname
@synthesize myLabel;
```

Now since you have written property(getter and setter methods) for UILabel, you can set its value from your first class only where you create object of second class.

```
SecondClass *secondObj = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
secondObj.myLabel.text = buttonClicked; //buttonClicked is NSString set when corresponding button is clicked e.g:1,2,3 etc.
```

Comment: I consider it bad design to have UILabel's etc as properties, the class that encapsulates them should be responsible for their updating, you should pass a data object to the class instead, and it then updates it's labels.

Comment: I agree @SimonLee.. Data Objects should be passed instead of design elements.